# MacOS terminal - wrong cursor position

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, macos-high-sierra

I have a problem with terminal because cursor is on the left side of window, and when i'm typing something, text is overlapsing "static" text with my username, but when i delete at least one letter, "static" text will delete (and looks like: $(cursor position)), but other cases is:

```
$(cursor position)-myMacName:~ myUserName
```

I expect:

```
$-myMacName:~ myUserName (cursor position)
```

Comment: Is it a problem with the shell or terminal, or with a program of yours?

Comment: +1 @Someprogrammerdude. It's more likely a program you are running is puting your cursor at this place. (out of the box, I suggest you to give a try to an alternative of MacOS terminal : https://www.iterm2.com/version3.html)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude macOS's terminal

Comment: @NathanGouy i used iterm but same problem

Comment: Then this question should be on [the SuperUser stack exchange site](https://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: are you running any kind of program ? Or you run this issue when you open your term ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with user name, IT dude created account with question mark, home directory had a extra space after name, and it was a problem, after delete and create a new profile, everything it's ok.